# How to save a class that extends AbstractTableModel into a file whenever it changes?

Tags: java, swing, reference, jtable

I have two classes. The first class `mainWindow extends JFrame` in there I have a JTable table1.
In my second class I need to get this table. When I generate a getter in the mainWindow I need to do `mainWindow win = new mainWindow();` in order to follow `win.getTable1();`. The problem is that the `mainWindow win = new mainWindow();` thing openes the window, so that I got it twice in the end. How can I get a reference to my table1 form my second class?

**mainWindow.java**

```
package windows;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import helpers.*;


public class mainWindow extends JFrame {

    private final String fileName = "Studenten";
    public studentTableModel model;
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JTable table1;
    private JButton generierenButton;
    private calculations calc = new calculations();

    public mainWindow() throws IOException {
        super("Zufallsgenerator fürs Repetieren");
        pack();

        setContentPane(rootPanel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 700);

        List<student> studentList = calc.readFromFile("Studenten");
        model = new studentTableModel(studentList);
        table1.setModel(model);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**studentTableModel.java**

```
package helpers;

import windows.mainWindow;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class studentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private calculations calc = new calculations();

    private final List<student> students;

    private final String[] columnNames = new String[] {
            "Id", "Name", "Bereits x-Mal repetiert", "Wahrscheinlichkeit", "im Pot"
    };

    private final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] {
            String.class, String.class, int.class, double.class, Boolean.class
    };

    public studentTableModel(List<student> students){
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
    {
        return columnClass[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        student row = students.get(rowIndex);
        if(0 == columnIndex) {
            return row.getId();
        }
        else if(1 == columnIndex) {
            return row.getName();
        }
        else if(2 == columnIndex) {
            return row.getAnzahlRepetitonen();
        }
        else if(3 == columnIndex) {
            return row.getWahrscheinlichkeit();
        }
        else if(4 == columnIndex) {
            return row.isInPot();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        student row = students.get(rowIndex);
        if(0 == columnIndex) {
            row.setId((String) aValue);
        }
        else if(1 == columnIndex) {
            row.setName((String) aValue);
        }
        else if(2 == columnIndex) {
            row.setAnzahlRepetitonen((Integer) aValue);
        }
        else if(3 == columnIndex) {
            row.setWahrscheinlichkeit((Double) aValue);
        }
        else if(4 == columnIndex) {
            row.setInPot((Boolean) aValue);
        }
        List<student> students1 = new ArrayList<student>();

        //here I need to get the table data to save it to a file using the method in the next class

        calc.saveToFile("newStudents", students1);

    }
}
```

**calculations.java**

```
package helpers;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class calculations {

    public void saveToFile(String file,List<student> studentList){
        int length = studentList.size();

        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        for (helpers.student student : studentList){
            String id = student.getId();
            String name = student.getName();
            int rep = student.getAnzahlRepetitonen();
            double wahrscheinlichkeit = student.getWahrscheinlichkeit();
            boolean inPot = student.isInPot();

            try {
                fileWriter.write(id + ";" + name + ";" + Integer.toString(rep) + ";" + Double.toString(wahrscheinlichkeit) + ";" + Boolean.toString(inPot) + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }

        try {
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<student>readFromFile(String file){
        List<student> studentList = new ArrayList<student>();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                student st = null;
                String[] cols = line.split(";");
                String id = cols[0];
                String name = cols[1];
                int rep = Integer.parseInt(cols[2]);
                double wahrscheinlichkeit = Double.parseDouble(cols[3]);
                boolean isPot = Boolean.parseBoolean(cols[4]);
                st = new student(id, name,rep, wahrscheinlichkeit, isPot);
                studentList.add(st);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return studentList;
    }

    public List<student> getTableData(JTable table, List<student> studentList){
        int rows = table.getModel().getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; rows >= i;){
            String id = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0);
            String name = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1);
            int anzahl = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);
            double prob = (Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
            boolean inPot = (Boolean) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 4);
            studentList.add(new student(id, name, anzahl, prob, inPot));
            System.out.println("Read row " + i);
        }
        return studentList;
    }

}
```

**changeListener**

```
table1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Change detected");
                List<student> newStudentList = new ArrayList<student>();
                calc.getTableData(table1, newStudentList);
                System.out.println("Now saving...");
                calc.saveToFile("newStudents", newStudentList);
            }
        });
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: And now please explain in more detail what you want to do.

Comment: @null allright. table1 is a editable table. in the beginning it takes its data from the "Studenten" file. Now I want to save the changes back to the file as soon as a cell gets changed. I tried it with a changeListener but it didnt work. so I tried calling the "saveToFile()" function, after the table model calls the setValueAt() function, since thats when the changes happen...

Comment: @null I edited my post at the bottom.
So, the program should have printed "Change detected" once there was a change in the table, but nothing happened...

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable at all and it's also unclear where it belongs to. I guess you noticed that yourself, thank you for editing your question.

Comment: Did your other classes looked like they do now in your question when you tried to get the `changeListener` to work? As it stands now, it's unclear what parts of the code that you posted belong to previous attempts and what parts are from getting the `changeListener` to work. I think we're getting close to something that can be answered.

Comment: @null the other parts of my code were more or less the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the program should have printed "Change detected" once there was a change in the table, but nothing happened.

it's true that [`addTableModelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#addTableModelListener%28javax.swing.event.TableModelListener%29) ...

> [...] Adds a listener to the list that's notified each time a change to the data model occurs.

but by extending the abstract class `AbstractTableModel` it's your responsibility to cause such notification with the provided methods such as [`fireTableDataChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29) for example. When you do that is up to you, but the method `setValueAt` looks like a good place to notify the listeners, because it's the one that changes the table data.